# PostgreSQL: permission denied for relation

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role, authorization

I'm a bit confused about setting permissions in PostgreSQL.

I have these roles:

```
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 admin     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 meltemi   | Create role, Create DB                         | {rails}
 rails     | Create DB, Cannot login                        | {}
 myapp     |                                                | {rails}
```

and databases:

```
                                    List of databases
        Name         | Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges 
---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 myapp_production    | rails  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 ...
```

user `myapp` has no problem querying the `myapp_production` database adding & deleting records. I'd like for `meltemi` to also be able to query the same database. So, I created a role `rails` which owns the database and made both `meltemi` and `myapp` members of `rails`. But I still get `permission denied for relation` errors. `Meltemi` can view the schema but can't query the DB.

I just noticed (with `\dt` command) that `myapp` is the owner of the tables:

```
             List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  | Owner 
--------+-------------------+-------+-------
 public | events            | table | myapp
 public | schema_migrations | table | myapp
 ...
 public | users             | table | myapp
 ...
```

The tables were created via an ORM (Rails' ActiveRecord migrations).

I know authorization is very different in PostgreSQL (as opposed to MySQL & others I've used). How should I be setting up my database so that different users can access it. Some should be able to CRUD but others may only be able to Read, etc...

Thanks for any help. Sorry, I know this is a very basic question but I haven't been able to find the answer myself.

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote about this in my answer to [Granting rights on postgresql database to another user](https://serverfault.com/questions/453777/granting-rights-on-postgresql-database-to-another-user) on ServerFault.

Basically, the best solution when you have a single user and you want to grant other users the same rights is to turn that user into a group, create a new user with the same name as the original one that's a member of the group, and grant that group to other users too.

So in your case, `rails` gets renamed to say `myapp_users`, then you create a new login role (user) named `rails` and `GRANT myapp_users TO rails`. Now you an `GRANT myapp_users TO meltemi`. Both the new `rails` account and the `meltemi` user now have the rights of the old `rails`account.

For more fine-grained control I ususally advise that you avoid giving the day-to-day login users or their groups ownership of the tables. Give them access via a `NOINHERIT` group they must explicitly `SET GROUP` to, or better, use a completely different user for privileged operations like DDL and `GRANT`s. Unfortunately this doesn't work with Rails, because Rails likes to apply migrations whenever it feels like it and AFAIK doesn't give you the ability to specify a different, more-privileged user to run the migrations as.

Comment: OK, read the post you linked to; very helpful! Now, if I'm understanding things right, I think you may have meant to use `myapp` instead of `rails` above? Because `myapp` owns the tables (I never specified that, the migration must have). Anyway, it would sorta make sense if I renamed `myapp` to `myapp_group` and then made a new user `myapp` which the rails app would use to connect to DB. Make `myapp` and the existing `meltemi`, both members of the `myapp_group` role. But what happens when I run the next migration. won't it be owned by `myapp` re-creating the problem all over again?!?

Comment: You must understand that PostgreSQL has only `roles` (since version 8.1). The terms `user` and `group` are kept around for historic reasons and compatibility. Basically a "group" is a role without the login privilege. You can grant `myapp` to `meltemi` even if `myapp` is just another "user". Start by reading the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createrole.html).

Comment: I DO understand the `roles` vs `groups` vs `users` separation in Postgres, at least I *think* I do. Sorry to use the wrong (and confusing) terminology above. But I *still* don't understand how to set up my database so a no-login role OWNS the database and two login roles `myapp` and `meltemi` can both have full access. One of those roles `myapp` will be running **Rails migrations** that will, inevitably?, create new tables that are, once again, owned by `myapp`, a login user. Should I just make `meltemi` a 'member' of `myapp` and be done with it? But that just seems kludgy...no?!?

Comment: @Meltemi: If you want to grant all privileges that `myapp` holds to `meltemi`, then that would be the right thing to do. If you want `meltemi` to get only a subset of privileges, it wouldn't. Then create a group role to hold the set of privileges and grant that to `meltemi`. You will most probably be interested in this [related question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10352695/939860). I answered explaining [`DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html#SQL-ALTERDEFAULTPRIVILEGES-NOTES)

Comment: @Meltemi Yes, as usual Rails migrations complicate the picture. Rails really should let you specify a *different* user account to run migrations as. You can possibly add a `SET ROLE` command to the start of your migrations and a `RESET ROLE` to the end, but I wouldn't trust Rails to run the whole thing neatly in order. Erwin's right; in this case the best workaround will be to `GRANT` the the user rails gives ownership to to the other user, using the 1st user as a group for the second.

Comment: so, am I understanding this correctly: I *could* `GRANT myapp TO meltemi` and then probably remove `meltemi`'s current membership in `rails` role. Or, I *could* `ALTER TABLE events OWNER TO rails`, etc. for each table. Then `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE myapp GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO rails;` so that any future migrations that Rails does will be owned by `rails` and not `myapp`?!? And as such available to `meltemi` who also is a member of `rails` (see OP). Does this make sense or am I still confounded by this seemingly perverse authorization in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Meltemi `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` has no effect on ownership, it only adds `GRANT`s. That's probably fine. I don't know why you find the authorization perverse; it's pretty ordinary role-based security. Rails is pretty perverse about how it uses databases, though.